# Coverflow in android?

Tags: android, coverflow

I created coverflow using below link
http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2011/03/images-with-coverflow-like-animation-in.html
Now my problem is when i click the particular image it shoud be displayed in another activity?
how it is possible.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: and please check if your question doesn't already exist. I've seen a couple of questions with exactly the same title.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code. Put it in your onCreate method.

```
        coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
                           //Handle event here.                 

        }
    });
```

Based on the position from coverflow create a intent, pass the value to some other activity which has an ImageView to display the selected Image.